# Android : Allow Cleartext http

Tags: android, http, android-9.0-pie, cleartext

I have a specific requirement wherein I have to block all http requests coming from the app, but there is a particular http url which a library uses which I have to whitelist. 
Tried setting the network_security_config xml as follows but can't load that http url. Have defined the network_security_config xml inside the manifest file as well.

Url is of the format http://abc.xyz.org

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">"abc.xyz.org"</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Is there something I'm missing here.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `xml/network_security_config` file with following domain rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <!-- As you want to pass domain-specific traffic -->
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <!-- Add your specific domain you want to pass without https -->
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">abc.xyz.org</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Add Network Security Config in Manifest:

```
<application android:label="your App Name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Comment: Not working. This isn't different from the code I wrote, the only difference is I mentioned <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted = "false"> explicitly which is anyways there by default as false. One more thing, I'm trying to load a webview with this Http URL